# Showing boundary around android-button

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

> How can i achieve this scenario:

[image]

> My android button tag in xml file:

```
 <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:text="Select Plan"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="#2D74B9"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Plan"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:textColor="#2D74B9"
            android:clickable="true" />
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#2D74B9" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will be your button xml

```
<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:text="Select Plan"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:background="@drawable/borderButton"
        android:textColor="#2D74B9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

And this will be your borderButton.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"


 android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke
    android:width="1dip"
    android:color="#2D74B9" />
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the following xml file under drawable folder let say abc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:radius="16dp"/>
<stroke
        android:color="#000000"
        android:width="3dp"

        />
</shape>
```

And,use it in your button background.

```
<Button
     android:background="@drawable/abc"/>
```